# PowerBI EnableFolding

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

September update have changed how to consume data from Postgres.

M code will change to something like this:

```
 Value.NativeQuery(PostgreSQL.Database("server", "db"), "query", null, [EnableFolding=true])
```

How can I change to function as before the update?

```
PostgreSQL.Database("server", "db", [Query="query"])
```

Or now I would need to do it manually?

Regards,

Comment: Did your code break? According microsoft it is "on top" .What have you tried so far? I could see you can add some extra values when making the connection, so to me it seems like your old situation should still work.

Comment: The first line of code works In PowerBI Desktop works, but at the moment of a refresh in PowerBI service retrieves an error.  Same applies with EnableFolding as **true** or **false**.
I personally don't need native queries, I was quite happy before the update. The error is:
`'EnableFolding' isn't a valid option for this function. Valid options are: (none)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Microsoft gave me the workarond: just remove  [EnableFolding=true] from query, advance editor (the one showing the m language)

Comment: That works! Thanks, but still ridiculous from their end.

Comment: How do you do this? What's the advance editor and where do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Right yesterday I went into the same issue. 
Data refresh now works only from desktop while fails for any new query created with latest Power BI once published on service.

Tried to set EnableFolding=false and EnableFolding=none as error message suggests but both throwing a error.

Comment: I tried both as you point out with the same result. **none** retrieves an error on PowerBI desktop and **false** retrieves an error on PowerBI service.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket to Microsoft.